# Intermittent IllegalArgumentException on ImagesService.applyTransform

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I started getting an `IllegalArgumentException` intermittently when calling the `applyTransform` method on `ImagesService` on Google App Engine.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
    at com.google.appengine.api.images.ImagesServiceImpl.convertApplicationException(ImagesServiceImpl.java:397)
    at com.google.appengine.api.images.ImagesServiceImpl.applyTransform(ImagesServiceImpl.java:88)
    at com.google.appengine.api.images.ImagesServiceImpl.applyTransform(ImagesServiceImpl.java:65)
    at com.google.appengine.api.images.ImagesService$applyTransform.call(Unknown Source)
```

This is my code:

```
protected byte[] convertToJpeg(byte[] tiffByteArray) {
    ImagesService imagesService = ImagesServiceFactory.getImagesService()

    Image oldImage = ImagesServiceFactory.makeImage(tiffByteArray)

    Transform transform = ImagesServiceFactory.makeRotate(0)

    OutputSettings outputSettings = new OutputSettings(ImagesService.OutputEncoding.JPEG)
    outputSettings.setQuality(40)
    Image newImage = imagesService.applyTransform(transform, oldImage, outputSettings)
    return newImage.imageData
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Check the [doc for the method](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/images/ImagesService.html#applyTransform-com.google.appengine.api.images.Transform-com.google.appengine.api.images.Image-com.google.appengine.api.images.OutputSettings-) you are using. It throws `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException - If transform, image or settings are invalid`. Breakpoints at each of the method input parameters would be useful to find out what is going on

Comment: Thanks @VictorHerasmePerez, the problem was that I was getting the error intermittently with the same exact inputs.

Comment: What is the situation now? Do you think you can provide a complete sample so we can reproduce it?

Comment: I ended up switching to `javax.imageio.ImageIO` which is available now that GAE supports the full classpath on Java 8.

Comment: Great. Can you describe what you did in an answer pls? It would be very helpful for the community

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never really figured out why it would intermittently throw an `IllegalArgumentException` for the same exact inputs, but I upgraded my GAE app to Java 8 which allowed me to use ImageIO:

```
protected byte[] convertToJpeg(byte[] tiffByteArray) {
    final BufferedImage tif = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(tiffByteArray))

    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    final ImageWriter writer = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("jpg").next()
    writer.setOutput(new MemoryCacheImageOutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream))

    JPEGImageWriteParam jpegParams = new JPEGImageWriteParam(null)
    jpegParams.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT)
    jpegParams.setCompressionQuality(0.4f)

    writer.write(null, new IIOImage(tif, null, null), jpegParams)

    return byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()
}
```

For TIFFs, this required an additional Gradle dependency:

```
compile group: 'com.github.jai-imageio', name: 'jai-imageio-core', version: '1.3.1'
```